# Installation issue in Docker

Tags: centos, docker

Install Docker is successful. But check the version it gives an error.

```
[root@ErandaCentOSSvr ~]# docker version
Segmentation Fault or Critical Error encountered. Dumping core and aborting. Aborted
```

Comment: What OS?  maybe try to run as sudo?

Comment: @rogerdpack He is running as sudo.